# Pollard's rho algorithm for logarithms_C with pointer error

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, discrete-mathematics

I was coding C about Pollard's rho algorithm from wiki, Pollard's rho algorithms for logarithms. But I had an runtime error which I don't know. I think it might be from pointer. Would you find the error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int alpha, beta, N;

void xab(int *x, int *a, int *b)
{
    switch(*x%3){
    case 0: *x=((*x)*(*x))%N;   *a=((*a)*2)%N;  *b=((*b)*2)%N;  break;
    case 1: *x=(alpha*(*x))%N;  *a=((*a)+1)%N;  break;
    case 2: *x=(beta*(*x))%N;   *b=((*b)+1)%N;  break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int x=1;    int a=0;    int b=0;
    int X=1;    int A=0;    int B=0;
    int i;

    scanf("%d %d %d", alpha, beta, N);

    for(i=1;i<N;i++){
        xab(&x,&a,&b);
        xab(&X,&A,&B);  xab(&X,&A,&B);
        if(x=X) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"But I had an error which I don't know."` It would be helpful if you'd share this error with us. Is it a compiler error, or a run-time error?

Comment: runtime error. Sorry for not writing about.

Comment: ......What is *exact text* of the the runtime error? Error messages exist for troubleshooting - I'm not sure why you're omitting them.

Answer (score 1):

```
 scanf("%d %d %d", alpha, beta, N);
```

should be

```
 scanf("%d %d %d", &alpha, &beta, &N);
```